# Dúvida sobre React (props ou state)

Tags: react

Boa tarde sou iniciante com React, comecei a ler a documentação dele e fiquei com uma pequena dúvida:
gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre prop e state?

E quando sei em qual momento devo usar uma prop ou um state?

Se puderem dar exemplos, eu aceito!

Comment: Se você entender inglês, esse artigo é excelente: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/props-vs-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos lá,Vou dar exemplificar e depois explico separados ok ? ok bora

### Exemplo

Sabe no html quando você chama a tag img criada por mim

**lado de fora do componente**

`<imgMy img="./SUaimg.jpg" CorFundo="red">Seu link</a>`

**Lado de dentro do componente**

```
<div background-Color={this.props.CorFundo}> <img src={this.props.img}/> </div>
```

Do lado de dentro do componente Viu como eu mando **props.CorFundo** e **props.img** ? do lado de fora onde eu instancio o componente eu chamo os mesmos nomes e passo parametros, no caso do que seria o **background** eu mando uma cor e oque seria a **src** eu mandaria uma imagem.

**Estado :**

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        aberto: true,
    }
}
```

Vamos dizer o seguinte eu tenho um outro componente que ele espera um parametro aberto, quando for true ele vai abrir uma janelinha pedindo para logar, vamos ver na pratica.

```
<button onclick={() => {this.setState({ aberto: true })}}/>

<JanelaLogar estaAberto={this.sate.aberto}/>
```

quando o estado aberto for alterado ele automaticamente vai mudar o o parametro que antes era false para true e logo em seguida o componente  vai ser alterado tambem por estar ligado ao estado, algo que dizem é que o o estado é o estado da verdade, coisas dinamicas na sua app sempre, casos a parte que não, vão estar ligadas ao estado.

Answer (score 1):

props = props séria a própriedade de tal class ou function, ex: tenho uma prop name em uma class/function pessoa.

state = state séria o estado daquela class, algo que você pode usar esse estado em diferentes partes do código, assim reutilizando ele.

não sei se me expressei muito bem!

Answer (score 1):

**State** é uma variável que pode apenas ser manipulada pelo componente na qual se encontra. Caso você queira que outro componente também receba esse state (por exemplo, para um componente com a funcionalidade de mostrar o valor do state), basta mandá-lo como **props**.

É importante notar que, o componente que irá receber as props NÃO pode modificar os valores do state do outro componente.

Answer (score 0):

As props são os atributos do seu componente.
O state diz respeito ao estado do seu componente.